# Missing rate per column per month in pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, missing-data

Let's take the following `pd.DataFrame`

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'M'   : ['1', '1' , '3',  '6',  '6',  '6'],
    'col1': [None, 0.1, None, 0.2,  0.3,  0.4],
    'col2': [0.01, 0.1, 1.3,  None, None, 0.5]})
```

which creates

```
    M   col1  col2
0   1   NaN   0.01
1   1   0.1   0.10
2   3   NaN   1.30
3   6   0.2   NaN
4   6   0.3   NaN
5   6   0.4   0.50
```

I would now like to have the missing rate percentage **per month per column**. The resulting table should look like this

```
M   col1  col2
1   50.0   0.0
3  100.0   0.0
6    0.0  66.6
```

where the values in the cells in `col1` and `col2` state the missing rates per month for the column.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) on the boolean columns:

```
out = (df.drop(columns='M').isna()  # check if the value is missing
         .groupby(df['M'])          # for each M
         .mean().mul(100).round(2)  # get the proportion x 100
         .reset_index()             # index as column
      )
```

output:

```
   M   col1   col2
0  1   50.0   0.00
1  3  100.0   0.00
2  6    0.0  66.67
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
df.set_index('M').isna().mean(level=0).mul(100).reset_index()
```

**Result**

```
   M   col1   col2
0  1   50.0   0.0
1  3  100.0   0.0
2  6    0.0   66.7
```